# multiple type of Validation through javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

i want to validate the text filed and multiple radio button field through the javascript.here is the form code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>script</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form name="myForm">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="job_id"  placeholder="*Booking/Job Id no : " >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="taxi_id" placeholder="* Driver Id/Taxi Id  " >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="first_name"  placeholder="*First name " >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="last_name"  placeholder="*Last name ">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
<div class="div1">
    <label>1. For how long have you been using our service?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset1" value="Less than a month">Less than a month <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset1" value="more then one month">more then one month <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset1" value="1-7 days">1-7 days <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset1" value="Less than a month">Never used <br>
</div><br>
<div class="div2">
    <label>2. How often do you use our  service?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset2" value="Everyday">Everyday <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset2" value="Once a week">Once a week <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset2" value="2 or 3 times a week">2 or 3 times a week <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset2" value="Once a month">Once a month<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset2" value="Less than once a month">Less than once a month<br>
</div>
<div class="div3">
<label>3. How satisfied are you with the service?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset3" value="Very Satisfied">Very Satisfied<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset3" value="Satisfied">Satisfied <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset3" value="Neutral">Neutral<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset3" value="Unsatisfied">Unsatisfied<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset3" value="Very Unsatisfied">Very Unsatisfied<br>
</div>
<div class="div4">
<label>4. What impressed you most about the service ?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset4" value="Quality">Quality<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset4" value="Price">Price<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset4" value="Sevice">Sevice <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset4" value="Customer Service">Customer Service<br>
</div>
<div class="div5">
<label>5. What disappointed you most about the service ?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset5" value="Quality">Quality<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset5" value="Price">Price<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset5" value="Sevice">Sevice <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldset5" value="Customer Service">Customer Service<br>
</div>
```

now i want to validate the radio button form also in the js file.what would be the shortest/best way?

Comment: You're using ordinary Javascript, why is this tagged `jquery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
var method = document.getElementsByName('fieldset1');
var ischecked_method = false;
for ( var i = 0; i < method.length; i++) {
    if(method[i].checked) {
        ischecked_method = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!ischecked_method)   {
   alert("Please choose something!");
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0sw19Lt1/4/)

EDITED :

http://jsfiddle.net/0sw19Lt1/13/

Comment: yes i want to do this but not in this way ..let us assume there are five fieldset of radio button and i want to validate in one go?@BipBip

Comment: You mean 5 questions with several radio buttons inside ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I don't know if it's close of what you wish..and the code isn't really elegant but it's just a fast thing you can do